# jQuery AJAX write to XML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'd like to write to an XML file using jQuery. Assume the following:

```
app.writeXML = function(data) {
    $.get("xml/sample.xml", function(resp) {
        var node = $(resp).find("Sample")
        $(node).append('<test>this is a test</test>')

        //write to the sample.xml file with the additional "test" node added

    }, 'xml')
}
```

Is the new node "test" appended to the end of my "Sample" node in local memory, or do I have an error here?

If it is in local memory only, I assume I need a server-side component to actually write to the file. What would this look like using PHP?

Comment: Yes you would need PHP to write the file again (at least, if you mean write it on the server), you could encode/decode it using JSON but if the changes you make are minor, consider making the changes in PHP and send the values/content through a POST request.

Comment: I'm not sure what the use case for writing directly to a single file would be . . . concurrency, handles, and state issues abound . . . why not a DB?

Comment: Use case is an internal helper tool. The xml file is used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you do on client side

1. get xml
2. build dom for it
3. add the node to the dom
4. And then nothing, it is all in browser

You actually have to implement some api on server side for changing the file. For example you may have a php file in which you work with the xml file and on client side just do post request to it.

Comment: What would this PHP file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it this way. What you might need to do is to have a post call in your jquery to post send the change and then have that update your xml.